# Regex (?:[,\\. ]*(&|and) ?) is not matching ', and "

Tags: java, regex

Regex `(?:[,\\. ]*(&|and) ?)` is not matching `", and "`. But when i change the matcher to `(?:[,\\.] ?(&|and) ?)` the pattern `", and "` is getting matched. What is causing pblm?

When i remove the space from `[,\\. ]*` it seems working. I simply dnt understand.

Comment: Regexes in which context/programming language?

Comment: @Kate, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

I can find the match even with the space. It would be helpful if you can post the exact code.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:[,\\. ]*(&|and) ?)");    
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(", and ");
System.out.println("Match? " + matcher.find());
```

Comment: You don’t want those backslashes.